# Can I justify removing a universal quantifier in this proof?

Tags: proof-writing, relations, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am trying to prove that the connex property implies reflexivity.

$\vdash (\forall x,\forall y :  (xRy \lor yRx)) \Rightarrow (\forall x : xRx)$

Here is my attempt

\begin{align*}
    &~~~~~(1)~~(\forall x,\forall y :  (xRy \lor yRx))\\ 
    &~~~~~~~~~~~\text{\{Justification ?? \}} \\
    &\Rightarrow(2)~~(\forall x :  (xRx \lor xRx)) \\
    &~~~~~~~~~~~\text{\{ Idempotency of disjunction in (2) \}}\\   
    &\equiv (3)\forall x : (x R x)\\
  \end{align*}
I am stuck for a justification between steps (1) and (2). The step seems intuitively valid. Do I need a sub-proof or is there some general rule that permits this step?

Comment: Am I correct in saying the the justification in the corrected question is two applications of universal instantiation followed by universal generalization?

Comment: $\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2 \end{array}}$Yes, the justification is basically that if a predicate is true for any $(x,y)$, then it is true for any $(x,x)$. $~[\forall x\forall y~P(x,y)]\to[ \forall x~P(x,x)]~$ Which may be proven by:$$\begin{array}{ll}\fitch{\forall x\forall y:P(x,y) }{\fitch{[a]}{\forall y:P(a,y)\\P(a,a)\\}\\\forall x: P(x,x)} &\raise{7ex}{\textsf{Premise}\\[0.5ex] \textsf{Arbitrary Witness}\\[0.5ex]\textsf{Universal Elimination}\\[0.75ex]\textsf{Universal Elimination}\\[2ex]\textsf{Universal Introduction}}\end{array}$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error is that you're trying to prove that the conclusion is *equivalent* to the premise, whereas you're actually just asked to prove that it *follows from* the premise.

In a typical formal proof system (here natural deduction) this can be done by almost what you're doing, except without the spurious $\equiv$ signs.

1. Assume $\forall x \forall y (xRy \lor yRx)$.
2. Universal instantiation, setting $x=x$, gives $\forall y (xRy \lor yRx)$.
3. Universal instantiation, setting $y=x$, gives $xRx\lor xRx$.
4. Propositional equivalece gives $xRx$.
5. Universal generalization gives $\forall x(xRx)$.
6. Discharge the assumption from step 1, giving $\forall x\forall y (xRy\lor yRx)\to \forall x(xRx)$.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by discharge the assumption? By step 5 we proved what what we wanted to prove; is "discharge the assumption" a phrase for "putting it all back together?

Comment: @Ovi That's standard logical jargon for "stop assuming", roughly. If you assume A and manage to derive B, you can then discharge the assumption A and assert $A\implies B$. After you do that, you can no longer use the previous hypothesis $A$. Note that a theorem, in this context, is a formula admitting a proof where all assumptions are discharged (otherwise, it's too easy to prove anything -- just assuming it).

Comment: @chi Ah okay thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can't justify the passage from $(1)$ to $(2)$. Let $R$ be the equality relation in a set with more than one element. Then $(1)$ is false (that is, there are distinct elements), whereas $(2)$ holds (each element is equal to itself).

Going from $(2)$ to $(3)$ is correct, since $P\vee P\iff P$.

Comment: Based on the comments I have replaced equivalence with implication. But I still do not understand the justification.

Comment: With the new version of the question, what you wrote is correct. Since, for every $x$ and every $y$, you have $x\mathrel{R}y\vee y\mathrel{R}y$, then, in particular, for every $x$ you have $x\mathrel{R}x\vee x\mathrel{R}y$. But note that you have completely changed the question.

Answer (score 3):

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2 \end{array}}\def\R{\operatorname{R}}$The justification is that: if a predicate is true for any $(x,y)$, then it is true for any $(x,x)$.

Should idempotence be a theorem you may use that; alternatively it may quickly be proven with disjunction elimination.

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{\forall x\forall y:x\R y\vee y\R x }{\fitch{[a]}{\forall y:a\R y\vee y\R a\\a\R a\vee a\R a\\\fitch{a\R a}{}\\a\R a\to a\R a\\a\R a}\\\forall x: x\R x} &\raise{12ex}{\textsf{Assumption}\\[0.5ex] \textsf{Arbitrary Witness}\\[0.5ex]\textsf{Universal Elimination}\\[0.75ex]\textsf{Universal Elimination}\\[0.75ex]\textsf{Assumption}\\[1ex]\textsf{Conditional Introduction}\\[1ex]\textsf{Disjunction Elimination}\\[2ex]\textsf{Universal Introduction}}\\ (\forall x\forall y:x\R y\vee y\R x)\to(\forall x:x\R x)& \textsf{Conditional Introduction}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt fails, because you try to prove the equality, not implication.

$$\forall x\in X \forall y\in X :(xRy \vee yRx)$$
$$\Rightarrow \forall x\in X \exists y=x\in X :(xRy \vee yRx)$$
$$\Rightarrow \forall x\in X  :(xRx \vee xRx)$$
$$\Rightarrow \forall x\in X  :(xRx )$$

Comment: Wait, where does an $\exists$ suddenly come from?

Comment: @HenningMakholm By the subalternation $\forall x: p(x) \Rightarrow \exists x :p(x)$

Comment: Just because something holds for all x it is not true that it holds for some x, since the set of all x could be empty.

Comment: As the connex relations are the subset of $X\times X$, the implication $\forall x\forall y p(x,y)\Rightarrow \forall x \exists y p(x,y)$ is totally ok (we know, that if there is at least one $x$, then $y$ is in non-empty set).